# Prevent scrolling but div needs position:absolute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigationbar

I still have problems with my slide-in menu. As far as I see, everything is ok but when the user scrolls down and open the menu via hamburger icon, the navi isn't viewable becaus it scrolls too.
So what I need is to make the navi sticky. But when I change the position (class: nav) from 'absolute' to 'fixed', the navi is outside my max-width (if screensize > max-width).

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $('input:checkbox').change(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
          $(".content").animate({ left: '-200px' });
          $(".content").css({"box-shadow": "0 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)" });
        } else {
          $(".content").animate({ left: '0' });
          $(".content").css({"box-shadow": "none" });
        }
    });

  });
```

```css
body {
  background-color:red;
}
h1 {
  padding: 10px 0 20px 0;
  font-size: 1.7em;
}
p {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  line-height: 18px;
}
.wrp {
  position:relative;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding:0 20px;
  height:100%;
  background-color:orange;
}
.header {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index:1000000;
}
.logo {
  float:left;
  width: 200px;
  border:solid red 1px;
}
.menu {
  float:right;
  border:solid black 1px;
  position:relative;
}
.content2 {
  padding:5px 10px;
  background-color:blue;
  color:white;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
.content {
  /* Critical position and size styles */
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color:blue; /* Needs a background or else the nav will show through */
  /* non-critical apperance styles */
  background-size: 200%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: right 0.5s;
}
.nav {
  position:absolute;
  width: 200px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 50px;
  background-color:green;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

/* hb icon */

.menu-icon {
  padding: 18px 14px; /* better clickable > please consider in header */
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

.menu-icon .navicon {
  background: #333;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  position: relative;
  width: 18px;
}

.menu-icon .navicon:before,
.menu-icon .navicon:after {
  background: #333;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .2s ease-out;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu-icon .navicon:before {
  top: 5px;
}

.menu-icon .navicon:after {
  top: -5px;
}

/* Nav Trigger */

.nav-trigger {
  /* critical styles - hide the checkbox input */
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

label[for="nav-trigger"] {
  /* critical positioning styles */
  right: 15px; 
  top:0;
  z-index: 3;

}

.nav-trigger:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon {
  background: transparent;
}

.nav-trigger:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.nav-trigger:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.nav-trigger:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:before,
.nav-trigger:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:after {
  top: 0;
}

/* Make the Magic Happen */
.nav-trigger + label, .wrp {
  transition: left 0.5s;
}

.nav-trigger + label {
  right: 15px;
  transition: right 0.5s;
}

.nav-trigger:checked + label {
  right: 215px;
}

.nav-trigger:checked ~ .nav {
  border: 4px solid red;
}

.nav-trigger:checked ~ .content {
  left: -200px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.18.1/build/cssreset/cssreset-min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  <div class="wrp">
    <div class="logo">Logo</div>
    <div class="menu">
      <input type="checkbox" class="nav-trigger" id="nav-trigger" />
      <label for="nav-trigger" class="menu-icon"><span class="navicon"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrp">
  <div class="content">
    <h1>This is my content</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
    <p>Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
    <p>Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
    <p>Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="nav">
    <h1>Navi</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

The Code on Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NxeLzY

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the nav container put a child container such as:

```
<div class="nav">
   <div class="nav-child">
      <h1>Navi</h1>
   </div>
</div>
```

Then set the styling so that the child container is fixed:

```
.nav-child{
   position:fixed;
}
```

See here for codepen solution:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mVazJq

Comment: Oh so easy but perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
In HTML replace:

```
 <div class="nav">
    <div class="inner_nav">
      <h1>Navi</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
```

In CSS add:

```
.inner_nav
{
  position:fixed;
}
```

Comment: How is this answer different than tdsymonds'?

Comment: it is not different - he posted his answer, while I was making mine/